how to get these icons to appear on my bone collections?
The bones of my model's armature are hidden and i cant make them appear. so i loaded the model again and notice this time it had these circle like icons on the bone collection.
how can i make these appear?


Are you sure bones are not individually hidden? In edit mode on the armature, press Alt + H.

The circle icons indicate in which bone collection the selected bones are. (You need to be in Edit or Pose mode to see the selected bones.) The filled circle/dot icon is for the active bone and the circle icons are for the other selected bones. You can add a bone to several collections using the Assign button. When you select this bone, you will see 2 or more dot icons, one for each collection it is in. The dot icon has priority and overwrites the circle icon.
